# Filtering JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce, intersect

Any guidance or reference is appreciated.

Using javascript's (map reduce and filter), I am trying to get a collection of all available rooms across multiple vendors in the given  JSON array. The logic for this :

**User Input **: checkIn Date, checkOut Date and Property Name

**Filter Logic **

- Check is the item availableFrom and availableTo dates fall in the range of checkIn and checkOut.
- Check if the item propertyName matches the user input
- Iterate through the items to get the common rooms

I have a JSON structure is :

```
var callOutResult = 
[
  {
    "vendorId": "1",
    "vendorName": "ABC",
    "vendorPropertyId": "100",
    "propertyName": "Some Name",
    "availableFrom": "2012-04-01T15:00:00.001Z",
    "availableTo": "2012-04-25T12:00:00.001Z",
    "available": {
      "floor1": ["101","105","106"],
      "floor2": ["202","204","208"],
      "floor3": ["301","304","307"],
      "floor4": ["405","409","410"],
      "floor5": ["502","504","506"],
      "floor6": ["602","607","609"]
    }
  },
  {
    "vendorId": "2",
    "vendorName": "XYZ",
    "vendorPropertyId": "300",
    "propertyName": "Some Name",
    "availableFrom": "2012-04-10T15:00:00.001Z",
    "availableTo": "2012-05-20T12:00:00.001Z",
    "available": {
      "floor1": ["104","106","107"],
      "floor2": ["208","214"]
    }
  },
  {
    "vendorId": "3",
    "vendorName": "PQR",
    "vendorPropertyId": "450",
    "propertyName": "Some Name",
    "availableFrom": "2012-01-23T15:00:00.001Z",
    "availableTo": "2012-06-25T12:00:00.001Z",
    "available": {
      "floor1": ["101","102","103"],
      "floor2": ["208","212"],
      "floor3": ["302","306","315"],
      "floor4": ["415","409","420"]
    }
  }
]
```

Code I have thus far

```
var checkInDate = new Date("2012-04-10");
var checkOutDate = new Date("2012-04-22");
var propertyName = 'Some Name'

// Check in & Check Out Date Filter
var filter1 = callOutResult.filter(function (arrayItem) {return arrayItem.availableFrom <= checkOutDate && arrayItem.availableTo >= checkInDate});

// Property Name Filter
var filter2 = filter1.filter(function (arrayItem) {return arrayItem.propertyName === propertyName});


result = Object
        .values(filter2)
        .reduce(function(a, b){
// CANNOT FIGURE OUT THE LOGIC TO ITERATE THROUGH THE rooms.
});
```

My goal is to filter the array to find available rooms. Reference to article, other sample code, anything that will guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to find the room(s) that fall within the specified checkin and checkout dates, have the required `propertyName` and are found in all the matched items, then the following might be helpful:

```js
var callOutResult = 
[
  {
"vendorId": "1",
"vendorName": "ABC",
"vendorPropertyId": "100",
"propertyName": "Some Name",
"availableFrom": "2012-04-01T15:00:00.001Z",
"availableTo": "2012-04-25T12:00:00.001Z",
"available": {
  "floor1": ["101","105","106"],
  "floor2": ["202","204","208"],
  "floor3": ["301","304","307"],
  "floor4": ["405","409","410"],
  "floor5": ["502","504","506"],
  "floor6": ["602","607","609"]
}
  },
  {
"vendorId": "2",
"vendorName": "XYZ",
"vendorPropertyId": "300",
"propertyName": "Some Name",
"availableFrom": "2012-04-10T15:00:00.001Z",
"availableTo": "2012-05-20T12:00:00.001Z",
"available": {
  "floor1": ["104","106","107"],
  "floor2": ["208","214"]
}
  },
  {
"vendorId": "3",
"vendorName": "PQR",
"vendorPropertyId": "450",
"propertyName": "Some Name",
"availableFrom": "2012-01-23T15:00:00.001Z",
"availableTo": "2012-06-25T12:00:00.001Z",
"available": {
  "floor1": ["101","102","103"],
  "floor2": ["208","212"],
  "floor3": ["302","306","315"],
  "floor4": ["415","409","420"]
}
  }
];
// convert date strings into Date objects:
callOutResult.forEach(e=>["From","To"].forEach(ft=>e["available"+ft]=new Date(e["available"+ft])));

var checkInDate = new Date("2012-04-10T15:10:00.001Z");
var checkOutDate = new Date("2012-04-22T09:00:00.001Z");
var propertyName = 'Some Name';

// check in & check out date and propertyName filter:
var filter = callOutResult.filter(function(itm) {
  return itm.availableFrom <= checkInDate && itm.availableTo >= checkOutDate && itm.propertyName === propertyName});

// check the existence of the room(s) for all matched vendors:
console.log(filter.map(e=>Object.values(e.available).flat(2)) // flatten rooms for each vendor
.reduce((a,c)=>{return a.filter(e=>c.some(f=>e==f))})) // a room must occur in each vendor object!
```

If the result should contain only those rooms (on their individual floors) that

- fulfil both timing and
- propertyName conditions
- *and* are only listed *once*,

then the following might be helpful:

```js
var callOutResult = [{"vendorId": "1","vendorName": "ABC","vendorPropertyId": "100","propertyName": "Some Name","availableFrom": "2012-04-01T15:00:00.001Z","availableTo": "2012-04-25T12:00:00.001Z","available": {"floor1": ["101", "105", "106"],"floor2": ["202", "204", "208"],"floor3": ["301", "304", "307"],"floor4": ["405", "409", "410"],"floor5": ["502", "504", "506"],"floor6": ["602", "607", "609"]}},{"vendorId": "2","vendorName": "XYZ","vendorPropertyId": "300","propertyName": "Some Name","availableFrom": "2012-04-10T15:00:00.001Z","availableTo": "2012-05-20T12:00:00.001Z","available": {"floor1": ["104", "106", "107"],"floor2": ["208", "214"]}},{"vendorId": "3","vendorName": "PQR","vendorPropertyId": "450","propertyName": "Some Name","availableFrom": "2012-01-23T15:00:00.001Z","availableTo": "2012-06-25T12:00:00.001Z","available": {"floor1": ["101", "102", "103"],"floor2": ["208", "212"],"floor3": ["302", "306", "315"],"floor4": ["415", "409", "420"]}}];

// convert date strings into Date objects:
callOutResult.forEach(e => ["From", "To"].forEach(ft => e["available" + ft] = new Date(e["available" + ft])));

var checkInDate = new Date("2012-04-10T15:10:00.001Z");
var checkOutDate = new Date("2012-04-22T09:00:00.001Z");
var propertyName = 'Some Name';

// check in & check out date and propertyName filter:
var dateProp = callOutResult.filter(function(itm) {
  return itm.availableFrom <= checkInDate && itm.availableTo >= checkOutDate && itm.propertyName === propertyName
});

const res = Object.entries(dateProp.reduce((a, e) => {
  Object.entries(e.available).forEach(([fl, rms]) => {
    let afl = a[fl] ??= {};
    rms.forEach(r => afl[r] = afl[r] ? afl[r] + 1 : 1);
  });
  return a;
}, {})).map(([fl, rms]) => Object.fromEntries([
  [fl, Object.entries(rms).filter(([r, cnt]) => cnt == 1).map(([r]) => r)]
]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. What I am trying to find is :

# 1. Rooms that are available by floor i.e. "available": {"floor1": ["101","102"..],"floor2": ["202","204",...], ....}

# 2. Rooms that do not overlap i.e. "available": {"floor1": ["107"],"floor2": ["202","204","212","214"], ....} in the given filter criteria.

Comment: Does "Rooms that do not overlap in the given criteria" mean they must only be mentioned _once_? If this is the case, then the following should be the expected result: `{floor1:[101,103,104,105,107], floor2:[202,204,212,214], floor3:[301,302,304,306,307,315], floor4:[405,410,415,420]}`